# How to manage constant geometry and changing color in OpenGL efficiently?

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

I have to draw multiple cubes (depending on data, ranging from 6k to, in an extreme case, 11k objects).

The cubes have fixed positions that do not change during the animation, however the color does change each frame. I reckon it is possible to draw geometry once, then just redraw the color, but how one can achieve that efficiently?

Also, I am a total beginner, so I do have only a basic understanding of OpenGL. 
What is the best practice (assuming the use of PyOpenGL)?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of [glBufferData](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) and carefully read the extra paragraph on the *usage* parameter. If you make positions and colours different buffers you can flag one static and the other dynamic - if this improves performance however is left to the implementation of your driver - so try before you buy (i.e. measure, measure, measure).

Comment: Thanks, but then what would be an optimal way to update the glBufferData? Call it each time and rebind to a different set of colors as the frame changes?

Comment: If all of the colours change then yes, `glBufferData` is probably the optimal way. Otherwise have a look at the **See Also** section in the documentation. What is optimal may change dramatically from driver to driver.

Comment: Thank you bery much. That is what I did. But now I have realised that having one vertex one color relation is awful lot waste of memory. Is there a way to avoid this? I mean is it possible to assign one color for multiple vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while but in the meantime I've solved this issue and thought that posting an answer might be helpful.

Generally, as [BeyelerStudios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426025/beyelerstudios) suggested, [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) can be used to determine if contents of one buffer are to be dynamically changed by setting `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` or `GL_STATIC_DRAW` as `usage` parameter.
However, there is a little more to this, as we can go even further.
I am going to use PyOpenGl to explain that but probably the same goes for C++ api.

Let's have a look at a set of functions that might be responsible for creating VBO's:

```python
def create_vbo(self):

    buffers = gl.glGenBuffers(2)
    # vertices buffer is static, so GL_STATIC_DRAW
    gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0])
    gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                    self.vectors_list,
                    gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    # colour buffer
    # note the parameter GL_DYNAMIC DRAW - this buffer will be rebound
    gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1])
    gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                    self.colour_vectors[self.i],
                    gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)
    return buffers

def vbo_cubic_draw(self):
    ... # make sure buffers are not None i.e. were created
    # actually replaces data in colour buffer
    gl.glBufferSubData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, self.buffer_len,
                                        colour_vectors[self.i])
    self.draw_vbo() # call drawing


 def draw_vbo(self):
    ... # enable client states
    # bind vertex buffer - will be static
    gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buffers[0])
    gl.glVertexPointer(4, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
    # bind color buffer which is dynamic
    gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buffers[1])
    gl.glColorPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
    ... # do more stuff and actually draw
```

Basically, `create_vbo` function declares two buffers: vertex buffer as static and colour buffer as dynamic. An extra step we can take is to make use of `glBufferSubdata` instead of `glBufferData` for dynamic buffer in `vbo_cubic_draw`. Then it is only required to redraw the colour buffer and then we actually can call some drawing function (e.g. `glDrawArrays`) in `draw_vbo`. Obviously, such approach requires two separate buffers, one for colour and one for vertices which is sometimes undesired. But looking at [`glBufferSubdata`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) doc, I don't think it's possible to use it for single interleaved buffers since we do have only *offset* parameter. Perhaps someone has a different take on that?
EDIT. Actually it might be very much possible if array is tightly packed and properly structured - I suspect you can use just one large buffer instead of many.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with specifically pyOpenGL, but I have plenty of experience with webGL and some with openGL, so hopefully this will be helpful.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by draw geometry once and then just draw color, do you mean just like have one buffer for position and one for color and then only change the color one? If so I don't think it's possible, because I think openGL can only handle one vertex attribute buffer at a time.

I would say that the best way to do this is to put all the cubes in the same buffer to reduce draw calls, and to set the buffer's usage to GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW as BeyelerStudios commented, as dynamic buffers are intended to be accessed frequently. You then update both the position and color data into this buffer when changing the color.

I hope this helps!

Comment: You can attach different vertex object buffers (attributes) with different usage hints to the same vertex array object or element draw call. Let's you share the same geometry with different materials using different shaders or render passes for example. See [glBindBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glBindBuffer)

Comment: [Tutorial2](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial2:_VAOs,_VBOs,_Vertex_and_Fragment_Shaders_(C_/_SDL)) holds an example of how to use two buffers to draw geometry with vertex colours.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I was not aware of that, we've never done that in any of the graphics classes I've taken.